# How come no one realizes that the Narrator in Bly Manor was talking about them?

Tags: the-haunting-of-bly-manor

The Netflix series *Haunting of Bly Manor* is shown as a story that's recalled by an old lady, named as **The Narrator**, to a set of guests of a Wedding Rehearsal.At the beginning of her story, The Narrator says the story is not related to her at all.

> However, at the end, she's revealed to be the older version of Jamie, the groundskeeper of Bly Manor.

So, she is definitely lying when she says the story isn't related to her at all. Let's say she does it to keep the secrecy of her identity. But there's a bigger issue. After the story is finished, and the guests have left for their rooms (the story is told at night),

> the Bride reveals that her middle name is Flora.

Forward to the scene where the guests are dancing, it's shown

> the Bride is indeed Flora, the little girl from Bly Manor and an old Henry Wingrave is shown dancing with her, while a grown up Miles watching the dance with a much older version of Owen.

The reason that Flora and Miles might not remember the haunting happened in Bly Manor, can be justified by the statements of Owen in the final episode

> They don't remember anything about it

> But I mentioned Hannah, and Flora asked me who I was talking about

Therefore we can excuse Flora and Miles for not remembering anything about the haunting things that happened in Bly Manor. Still, they are said to remember Bly Manor as the place they grew up, so it's amusing that none of them suddenly realized the story strongly resembles to their lives. However there's no excuse for Owen and Henry Wingrave, who apparently didn't forget what happened in Bly Manor. It's surprising none of them suddenly go

> "Hey I think I've heard this story before. And you seems very familiar. Is that you, Jamie?"

So why, none of them is shown to realize The Narrator is telling a story about them?

Comment: They don't remeber it because it's "supernatural". I would ask question "why go and tell story about dead people and death at a wedding rehearsal?"

Comment: Well, Jamie, Owen are at the wedding. That means probably Henry invited them. He most likely remembers, I donot think it was indicated otherwise in the series. As for the kids, they are probably too traumatised to recall any of that.

Answer (score 2):

Midway through the final episode, Owen (the chef) says that the children have completely forgotten about the events. They don't remember Jamie, or Hannah. They don't even remember much about Bly, just "A place we stayed one Summer." Owen also says that, although Henry (the uncle) hasn't forgotten about the events, he rarely talks about them.

Flora and Miles, then, wouldn't recognize any of the story. It's possible (likely) that Henry has also forgotten about it. The older Owen clearly recognizes Jamie, but he chooses not to reveal that the story is a true one. In the scene where he says the children have forgotten the events at Bly, he also says he won't tell them about it. He thinks it's better that they forget such traumatic experiences.

Comment: This of course and the Narrator is also supposed to be an unreasonable one...

Answer (score 0):

Owen and Henry DO recognize Jamie. But they keep quiet. At the beginning of the very first episode, when older Owen is making a toast, his expression changes when he sees Jamie.

Personally, I was more surprised that none of the older versions - the kids nor the adults - even slightly resemble their younger versions... except older Jamie could *maybe* pass for younger Jamie.
I blame casting for that.